# using smarty template engine in registered javascript files with prestashop 1.7

Tags: javascript, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm writing Prestashop 1.7.2.1 module.

In that module when I want to register a javascript file I connect to the hook `actionFrontControllerSetMedia` and use `registerJavascript` like so:

```
    $this->context->controller->registerJavascript('module-tuxinmodcartype-carsearch-js','modules/'.$this->name.'/js/displaytop.js');
```

this loads the javascript properly but I can't use smarty template engine in those javascript files.

is there a way to do that ? :)

if not... should I just add all my javascript files inline ?

## update

so I added this to my hook function:

```
 Media::addJsDef(['tuxinmodcartype'=>array(
        'car_companies'=>$this->tuxDb->getCompanyNamesArray()
    )]);
```

and this my js file:

```
$(function() {
    var options = {
        data: tuxinmodcartype.car_companies,
        list: {
            match: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    };

    $('#company-name-input').easyAutocomplete(options);

});
```

and I get the error `ReferenceError: tuxinmodcartype is not defined`

Comment: Why would you want to use smarty in javascript files? You want smarty variables in javascript?

Comment: @TheDrot - it would be cool if could even use smarty if satements to build the javascript file. yeah but the most of it it's variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For accessing variables in javascript you can assign them in your controllers with:

```
Media::addJsDef(array(
    'mymodule' => array(
        'var1' => 'yes',
        'var2' => 'no'
    )
));
```

Then you can use them in your javascript or through console:

```
let var1 = mymodule.var1;
let var2 = mymodule.var2;
```

Building javascript files with smarty... I guess it's better to split javascript into more files and load them through controller based on conditions. Or use the above definition for variables to control execution path in your javascript.

Comment: thank you very much. first the code example that you provided is missing an initial [] in the parameters of the addJSDef function right? updated main post. still have a problem

Comment: @ufk Yes you're right it was missing an initial array. Can you access your variable from developer console?

Comment: nope. can't.. again.. i'm trying to write tuxinmodcartype, there is no code completion and I get reference error

Comment: maybe i had cache problems one sec

Comment: after resetting the cache the developer console auto completes the variable but when I try to "console.info(tuxinmodcartype);" i get that it's not defined

Comment: Maybe PS 1.7 deprecated this way of js variable defining because it works fine in 1.6 and I don't have 1.7 installed atm to try, however I see that this method still exists in 1.7 `Media` class. I guess you could make a workaround by also using `displayTop` hook and output a smarty template with `<script>let myvars = {$mysmartyvars|json_encode}</script>`. But then you'll have to wrap your javascript in a `$(document).ready` function.

Comment: your other way works... but this function doesn't seem deprecated.. i'll see what's going on :)

Comment: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/357269-prestashop-16-addjsdef-not-working/ - found this.. in prestashop 1.7 I need to set an advanced feature to move the javascript code to the end. so I'm just defining variables in the javascript file and then use them elsewhere. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Safer way to declare your vars without mymodule array,

```
Media::addJsDef(array('var1' => $myphpvar));
Media::addJsDef(array('var2' => $myphpvartwo));
```

this way you DONT need

```
let var1 = mymodule.var1;
```

Why this better? Because 'let var1' cause error in iphone safari browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this in the tpl file:

```
<script>var = '{$var}';</script>
```

and use your var in the javascript file.

Source: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/589645-unknown-tag-addjsdef-error/?tab=comments#comment-2490210